# How to set 48k shared memory for CUDA in VisualStudio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, gpu, gpu-shared-memory

I want to switch into 48k shared memory in CUDA but I don't know how to set the option in VisualStudio 2008.

Answer (score 3):

The ShMem/L1 configuration is done independently of you IDE. You should call either [`cudaFuncSetCacheConfig`](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__EXECUTION_g400ecf473d4fa8ac6738fbc753d5c288.html#g400ecf473d4fa8ac6738fbc753d5c288) or [`cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig`](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__DEVICE_gac27b566beee1aa9175373bb9e29b8d1.html). The former affects cache settings for only one specified function, the latter is global.

Of course, you should have compatible device (CC >= 2.0). Also, 48KiB ShMem is default configuration.